# React Native flexbox rows aligning items

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

How can I get a layout like this without using a static width?

[image: Layout]

The text before the "•" should be aligned to the left, but the text after the "•" should all be inline with each other. To get it looking like that I've used a static width, but for obvious reasons, that's not so good.

Here's the React Native code:

```
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    margin: 2,
    borderColor: 'green',
    borderStyle: 'solid',
    borderWidth: 2,
  },
});

const RoleRow = ({ role }) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={{ width: 55 }}>
      {role.name}
    </Text>
    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
      {` • ${role.person.name} ${role.person.lastName}`}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

Comment: Consider placing the `role.name` and the bullet point in one container. Pin them to opposite edges with `space-between`. Give that box a min-width. Then append the `role-person-name` by itself in a second container.

Comment: Sounds like it could work, I'll try that now

Comment: That doesn't solve it. It's still relying on a static width. If you have dynamic length data, then you still have issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help.  It might be a bit strange but you'll have to treat each item as a column instead of a row but here is a [codepen](https://codepen.io/kriddy800/pen/mjNwJq?editors=1100)

HTML

```
 <div class="cont">
      <div class="role-col">
        <div class="role">Small Role</div>
      </div>
      <div class="name-col">
        <div class="name">Small Name</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

SCSS

```
.cont{
  width:400px;
  height:400px;
  background-color:green;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;

  .role-col,.name-col{
    .role,.name{
      border-top:1px solid black;
      border-bottom:1px solid black;
      margin-top:8px;
    }
  }

  .role-col{
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    background-color:red;

    .role{
      border-left:1px solid black;
      margin-left:8px;
      padding-right:4px;
    }
  }

  .name-col{
    display:flex;
    flex:1;
    flex-direction:column;

    .name{
      border-right:1px solid black;
      margin-right:8px;
      padding-left:4px;
    }
  }
}
```

What this does is there must be an item in each column for the role and name.  So if you have a name with no role or a role with no name you will have to add an empty item in the column so the css can size them correctly.  If you have any questions please let me know

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that column layout may work better. Not as nice a rows, but at least this works. Good example btw. I'm going to test it out and get back to you. Thanks!

Comment: Great job! Just tried it out, works exactly like I want 

Comment: See my answer for React Native version https://stackoverflow.com/a/52169818/7304372

Answer (score 1):

Here's a simple React Native version of [kriddy800's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51896207/7304372). Same thing, just formatted to better answer my question. Thanks [kriddy800](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6430954/kriddy800)!

```
 <View style={{ flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row' }}>
  <View>
    <Text>
      Spaceship building
    </Text>
    <Text>
      Piano
    </Text>
  </View>
  <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
      • John F. Kennedy
    </Text>
    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 5 }}>
      • Francis Dunget
    </Text>
  </View>
</View>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `flex`:

```
const RoleRow = ({ role }) => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
    <Text style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      {role.name}
    </Text>
    <Text style={{ marginLeft: 5, flex: 3 }}>
      {` • ${role.person.name} ${role.person.lastName}`}
    </Text>
  </View>
);
```

That will give a 1-3 proportion to the Text areas.

Comment: This works with the data I've supplied. But, since it's dynamic data, if I were to be given `role.name = 'Spaceship building'` and `role.person = 'John F. Kennedy'`, you'd notice that the role goes over multiple lines, while the person has lots of room after it. I'm thinking it might work better to have two columns instead of multiple rows

Comment: @ElliotSchep In this case, you can limit the max characters to be shown for the first column, or add three dots after the text, etc.. Does it fit your requirements?

Comment: It does not. All the text must be displayed. If it can't be solved, then I'll just live with the text not inline.